# Rails custom client side validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, simple-form, client-side, client-side-validation

My custom validation does not work on client side. can someone see why? **validate_each is not called. It takes error message for named_regexp directly in model.**

```
// app/validators/named_regexp_validator.rb

class NamedRegexpValidator < ActiveModel::EachValidator
  ERROR_MESSAGE = "Regexp group names are required"

  def check_validity!
    unless valid_groups && valid_groups.kind_of?(Array) && valid_groups.any?
      raise ArgumentError, ERROR_MESSAGE
    end
  end

  def validate_each(record, attribute, value)
    if value.present?
      regexp = Regexp.new value, false

      if regexp.names.none?
        record.errors.add attribute, :blank_regexp_group
      else
        extra_groups = regexp.names - valid_groups

        if extra_groups.any?
          record.errors.add attribute, :named_regexp, allowed: valid_groups.join(', '), extra: extra_groups.join(', ')
        end
      end
    end
  end

  private

  def valid_groups
    options[:groups]
  end
end
```

In model my validation looks like this:

```
validates :regexp_string, named_regexp: { groups: %w(name surname) }
```

In haml view it is a simple input

```
= f.input :regexp_string, as: :string
```

I am using:

```
gem 'nested_form'
gem 'simple_form'
gem 'client_side_validations', github: 'DavyJonesLocker/client_side_validations'
gem 'client_side_validations-simple_form', github: 'DavyJonesLocker/client_side_validations-simple_form'
```

When I press submit button and I have a bad regexp validation does not through an error. 
Also I am having problem adding presence validation on regexp field from js if other form option selected. I add requred: true but still nothing, how can I force it?

|| EDIT:

I found that there is a way to add those client-side validations by:

```
ClientSideValidations.validators.local["named_regexp"] = function(element, options) {
  var s = element.val();

  if (ADD_ALL_VALIDATIONS_HERE) {
    return options.message;
  }
}
```

But it is too complicated, I can't believe there is no easier way. Or someone knows it?

Comment: In your model, try `validates_with NamedRegexpValidator`; I don't think Rails will use the validator unless you explicitly tell it to.

Comment: Well they should use it, since I am telling to use it already with `named_regexp`. Or I am mistaken?

Comment: Try using the syntax I gave instead.